# ASP.NET: gridview sorting using XSLT not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xslt, gridview

I am quite new to XML-XSLT coding. 
I am binding XmlDataSource to my gridview by using XSLT. I want to sort the column upon clicking on the header. I do not want to convert xml to dataset and bind to gridview to achieve sorting. Here is my code:

```
<asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource1" runat="server"></asp:XmlDataSource>
<asp:GridView ID="gvResult" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center" AutoGenerateColumns="false" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#3AC0F2" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" AllowPaging="True"
    OnPageIndexChanging="gvResult_PageIndexChanging" AllowSorting="true" OnSorting="gvResult_Sorting">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="ID">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl='~/NewForm.aspx?ID=<%# XPath("@ID") %>'> 
                    <%# XPath("@ID") %>
                </asp:HyperLink>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="employee_number" HeaderText="Employee Number"  SortExpression="last_name"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="Employee Name" SortExpression="last_name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="date_joining" HeaderText="Joining Date" SortExpression="date_joining" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="date_paid" HeaderText="Date Paid" SortExpression="last_name"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="amount" HeaderText="Salary"  />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="status" HeaderText="Status" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>


protected void gvResult_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
         XsltArgumentList xslTrnsform = new XsltArgumentList();
        switch (e.SortExpression)
        {
            case "employee_number":
                xslTrnsform.AddParam("sortby", "", "employee_number");
                xslTrnsform.AddParam("order", "", "ascending");
                //xslTrnsform.AddParam("datatype", "", "number");
                break;
            case "date_joining":
                xslTrnsform.AddParam("sortby", "", "@date_joining");
                xslTrnsform.AddParam("order", "", "ascending");
                //xslTrnsform.AddParam("data-type", "", "text");
                break;
            case "date_paid":
                xslTrnsform.AddParam("sortby", "", "@date_paid");
                xslTrnsform.AddParam("order", "", "ascending");
                //xslTrnsform.AddParam("data-type", "", "text");
                break;
        }

        XmlDataSource1.EnableCaching = false;
        XmlDataSource1.Data = ResponseObj.OuterXml;

        XmlDataSource1.TransformArgumentList = xslTrnsform;
        XmlDataSource1.TransformFile = "employees.xslt";
        XmlDataSource1.XPath = "/employees/employee"; ;

        // Bind the DataSet to the grid view
        gvResult.DataSource = XmlDataSource1;
        gvResult.DataBind();
        gvResult.Visible = true;
    }



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:param name="sortby" select="@employee_number"/>
  <xsl:param name="order" select="'ascending'"/>

  <xsl:template match="employees">
    <employees>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="employee">
      <xsl:sort select="*[name()=$sortby]" order="{$order}" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
    </employees>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="employee">
    <employee>
      <xsl:attribute name="ID">
        <xsl:value-of select="@ID"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="employee_number">
        <xsl:value-of select="@employee_number"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="name">
        <xsl:value-of select="@last_name"/>, <xsl:value-of select="@first_name"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="date_joining">
        <xsl:value-of select="@date_joining" />
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="dte_to_date">
        <xsl:value-of select="@dte_to_date" />
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="date_paid">
        <xsl:value-of select="@date_paid"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="date_paid">
        <xsl:value-of select="@date_paid"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="amount">
        <xsl:value-of select="@amount"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="status">
      <xsl:value-of select="@status"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
    </employee>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Data is displayed on the gridview. But when I click on header, nothing happens. Also I have to apply sorting for "name" column, which consists of lastname,firstname.

Comment: Why are you using this verbose xsl:element/xsl:attribute format? Either use AVTs: `<employee ID="{@ID}" empNr="{@empNr}" etc/>`, or use `<xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem you have is you are inconsistent about how you are setting the `sortby` parameters. In one place you do this...

```
 xslTrnsform.AddParam("sortby", "", "employee_number");
```

But in another place you do this...

```
 xslTrnsform.AddParam("sortby", "", "@date_joining");
```

As it looks like all your data is held in attributes, for the sake of consistency, it might be easier to drop the `@` prefix in all cases. Then, your `xsl:sort` can look like this

```
 <xsl:sort select="@*[name()=$sortby]" order="{$order}" />
```

(Previously you were doing `select="*[name()=$sortby]` which would look for elements not attributes.)

To get your `name` column to sort by `last_name` and `first_name` you could add a second sorting parameter

```
case "name":
   xslTrnsform.AddParam("sortby", "", "last_name");
   xslTrnsform.AddParam("sortbysecond", "", "first_name");
   xslTrnsform.AddParam("order", "", "ascending");
   break;
```

Then, assuming you declare the `sortbysecond` parameter in your XSLT, your sort would look like this

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="employee">
  <xsl:sort select="@*[name()=$sortby]" order="{$order}" />
  <xsl:sort select="@*[name()=$sortbysecond]" order="{$order}" />
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

Try this XSLT...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:param name="sortby" select="'employee_number'"/>
  <xsl:param name="sortbysecond" select="'employee_number'"/>
  <xsl:param name="order" select="'descending'"/>

  <xsl:template match="employees">
    <employees>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="employee">
      <xsl:sort select="@*[name()=$sortby]" order="{$order}" />
      <xsl:sort select="@*[name()=$sortbysecond]" order="{$order}" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
    </employees>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="employee">
    <employee ID="{@ID}" 
              employee_number="{@employee_number}"
              name="{@last_name}, {@first_name}"
              date_joining="{@data_joining}"
              dte_to_date="{@dte_to_date}"
              date_paid="{@date_paid}"
              date_paid="{@date_paid}"
              amount="{@amount}"
              status="{@status}">
    </employee>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note the use of [Attribute Value Templates](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates), as Michael Kay mentioned in comments, which simplify your XSLT greatly.

Comment: I am sorry, I was not getting time to try. Thank you Tim & Michael. Sorting is working now. Tim, I have tested the code provided by you.